# state machine run-to-completion paradigm

Tags: uml

I did not understand the paradigm run-to-completion about state machine (14.2.3.9.1 UML 2.5 spec). At one point he says:

"Run-to-completion means that, in the absence of exceptions or asynchronous destruction of the context Classifier object or the StateMachine execution, a pending Event occurrence is dispatched only after the processing of the previous occurrence is completed and a stable state configuration has been reached. That is, an **Event occurrence will never be dispatched while the StateMachine execution is busy processing the previous one**"

and in another:

"IMPLEMENTATION NOTE. Run-to-completion is often mistakenly interpreted as implying that an executing StateMachine cannot be interrupted, which, of course [of course?? NDR] would lead to priority inversion issues in some time-sensitive systems. However, this is not the case; in a given implementation a thread executing a **StateMachine step can be suspended**, allowing higher-priority threads to run, and, once it is allocated processor time again by the underlying thread scheduler, it can safely resume its execution and complete its event processing"

So, is possible or not interrupt the state machine?? A new high priority event can interrupt the current event dispatch?

Thanks

Mauro

Answer (score 4):

The implementation note refers to hard- or software implementation on a higher level. The completion is only valid for the context of the state machine. This machine may run in a global context which can allow to interrupt the processing of the state machine. But the state machine will not notice this interruption and from its own view it still continues processing. So, as mentioned, the only issue is that the state machines personal watch will not run continuously but with irregular jumps. In normal business processes this can be neglected, but when dealing with real-time-processing, you might get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

"an Event occurrence will never be dispatched while the StateMachine execution is busy processing the previous one" means that a StateMachine will not select the next Event from its queue until its run-to-completion step is completed. This does not prevent the state machine itself or other state machines from sending further events into its queue, while the run-to-completion step is running.
Moreover, a run-to-completion step might become suspended in the case of a synchronous Operation Call; the run-to-completion step will later be resumed when the operation call is completed (possibly returning a value).